# Why does the search filter in the Google Play Store App not work?

Tags: android, search, google-play

I'm asking this on behalf of a client. I've checked and this question is on topic for stack overflow.

1. Go to https://play.google.com
2. Search for '2nd Ave Shopper' - The app shows up.
3. Open the Google Play Store App on your Android phone.
4. Search for '2nd Ave Shopper' - The app does not show up.

Why is this?

I've added the keywords '2nd Ave Shopper' in the description. Is there something else I can do to make it show up on the Google Play Store App?

Comment: I have been searching in the meantime, but no one has come across this. The name of the app is '2ndAveShopper', but we have '2nd Ave Shopper' in the description so it should still be returned when searched for. Has anyone here had any luck with previous apps?

Comment: There's also no tags section in Google Play anymore.

Comment: Could it be because the phone you use is not supported by the app? If you log in with the same Google account on your PC, it should say something like "2 of your devices are supported by this app", and list the devices that are supported and unsupported. Is the device you try to search from on the list of supported devices?

Comment: Thanks Erland D, that might be it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could it be because the phone you use is not supported by the app?

If you log in with the same Google account on your PC, it should say something like "2 of your devices are supported by this app", and list the devices that are supported and unsupported.

Is the device you try to search from on the list of supported devices?